# Regex to match multiple MBCS strings on any line

Tags: c++, regex, string

I'm looking for a regex to match only MBCS strings inside of a C++ project. Those are strings contained in double quotes without a `L"..."` or `_T("...")` specifier. There can be multiple quotes on any line of code. Strings can contain escaped substrings that shouldn't end the match. Here are a few examples:

```
"This is a MBCS string"; // "This is a MBCS string" match
_T("This is maybe a unicode string"); // no match
L"This is a unicode string"; // no match
"These both" + "should match"; // "These both" and "should match" match
"This is a \"quoted\" string"; // "This is a \"quoted\" string" match
```

I have a regular expression than can handle all of this fine using negative lookbacks `(?<!#include )(?<!_T\()(?<!\\)(?<!L)\"(.*?)\"(?<!\\\")` but it gets more complicated yet. It starts to have problems with mixing of string types on one line.

```
_T("Maybe this") + "is a match"; // "is this" match but instead would match ") + "
do_something(_T("This doesn't match")) + do_something("but this does match"); // "but this does match" match but instead it matches ")) + do_something("
```

How can I have the regular expression not match on `_T("")` and `L""` words but still match them to eat the end quote without returning it as a match?

Edit: This regex, `(?:_T\(\"[^\"]+\"\).*?|L\"[^\"]+\".*?)*(?<!#include )(?<!_T\()(?<!L)(?<!\\)\"(.*?)\"(?<!\\\")`, nearly does the job but there is one more test case that's failing that I hadn't thought to include originally.

```
_T("don't match this") + _T("or this"); // shouldn't match anything, matches ") + _T("
```

Comment: Can't you match all of them and then filter out those that begin with `L` or `_T(`?

Comment: If your strings are well-formed, I would extract every `(?:L|_T\s*\(\s*)?"(?:[^\"]+|\\")*"` string and then examine whether it has a prefix before the opening quote.

Comment: Yes that is definitely a thought. I was wondering if there was an easy way to come up with a proper regex but that looks to be harder and harder as I run it through some real files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might actually match the `_T` and `L` parts so that they are consumed in a previous match:

```
(?:_T\(\"[^\"]+\"\).*?|L\"[^\"]+\".*?)?(?<!#include )(?<!_T\(|L|\\)\"(.*?)\"(?<!\\\")
```

I also shortened the negative lookbehinds.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lM2tK3)

Comment: That works, thanks! In order to use it with Python I had to expand the shortened look behind, it only operates on fixed length look behinds, so I ended up with the following `(?:_T\(\"[^\"]+\"\).*?|L\"[^\"]+\".*?)?(?<!#include )(?<!_T\()(?<!L)(?<!\\)\"(.*?)\"(?<!\\\")`.

Comment: @Kyle Oh, okay, understandable, that means though that you should still be able to use `(?<!L|\\)` instead of `(?<!L)(?<!\\)` :)

Comment: It's a good solution to the problem I proposed but I missed out on a big test case in my original example with two escaped strings `_T("test"), _T("case")`. It doesn't match the non-capture group and hits between the two strings with `), _T(` which is wrong. It's possible to capture zero characters or the main capture as far as I can tell but that breaks the Python substitution by capturing nothing on most lines and throwing an exception. It might just be easiest to capture any string @tripleee and check external to the regex if it's a MBCS string.

Comment: @Kyle You have consecutive 'false matches' as well (if I can call those like that)? You can turn the `?` into `*` so that more of them can be skipped. You can also test different cases [here](http://regex101.com/r/hP0kR7) (I already added one case of two consecutive `T("...")` there).